# android reloading data from server makes duplicates

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an app and when I try to update some of the information like user personal information I call to the user information service once again for updated data but instead of updated data it shows me the old data. It only shows me the updated data when I logout from app and sign in again, because at logout I delete all table values and at sign in it fetches new values from server. I don't know you this happens please help me in solving this problem.

here is how I am saving the data to the DB that comes from server
This is the DBHandler class

```
public boolean SaveUserData(ContentValues values , String tablename)
{
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = DatabaseHundler.open();
    try{
        if(dataBase != null)
        {
            if (values!= null)
            {
                dataBase.insertWithOnConflict(tablename,
                        BaseColumns._ID, values,
                        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

and Tables class code is

```
public void InsertData(ContentValues values) 
{


    Controller.hundler.SaveUserData(values, TableName);

}
```

And this is how I am getting data from `JSON` and inserting to table:

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject dataObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String valueForField;
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    Controller control = (Controller) context.getApplicationContext();
    for(int j=0; j<control.Table_user.colmnNames.size(); j++){
        String key = control.Table_user.colmnNames.get(j);
        valueForField = Utility.getStringFromJsonObject(dataObject, key);
        String type = (valueForField.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))? "" : valueForField;
        value.put(control.Table_user.colmnNames.get(j), type);
    }
    control.Table_user.InsertData(value);
}
```

Comment: you have to use update method for that.

Comment: can you give an example how can I do it please using above values?

Comment: you have to compare your id or primary key for their data to update.